# bcrypt genSalt never returns

Tags: javascript, node.js, bcrypt

I'm trying to use `genSalt` from the `bcrypt` package method but it run forever.

I tried to set the `rounds` value to `1` and also to use the sync version of the method but it never returns.

```js
console.log("A");
const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(1);
console.log("B");
const pwd_hash = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);
console.log("C");
```

The console only display "A".

I'm using `nestjs` and my app is running is a docker container.
The problem doesn't occurs when the app is runned outside the docker container.

- Node.js `v18.17.1`
- bcrypt `^5.1.1`

Comment: There's not enough information in your snippet to help you. What errors are you getting? What have you tried? have you tried logging out all the  variables to see if they are actually returning anything? have you tried hardcoding the password to see if it works that way?

Comment: "but it never returns" how do you know that? Also, what version of node.js? If you're using a really old one with no Promise support, well your code would syntax error from async and await but something's weird here.

Comment: [Your code just works](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-wevlxa?description=Starter%20project%20for%20Node.js,%20a%20JavaScript%20runtime%20built%20on%20Chrome%27s%20V8%20JavaScript%20engine&file=index.js,package.json&title=node.new%20Starter) ^^

Comment: @JaredSmith I'm using node v18. I put `console.log` in-between method call to see what method cause my app to freeze.

Comment: I can't reproduce, your code works fine. What happens if you strip it down to just the code in the question instead of your full nest app and just run that? Does that fail too?

Comment: I moved the code before the nest app start and I got the same problem. But when I run the app outside the docker container it's work fine. It's possible to have a conflict between bcrypt and docker?

Comment: @tguichaou are you installing node dependencies directly in the docker container or on something else and then copying them over? Because the bcrypt package uses node-gyp to run C++ code and that's architecture-dependent: if you compile for say, Apple silicon and then try to run that code in a x64 docker image you'll get a segfault which could explain your problem.

Comment: ...if you are copying over the node_modules folder, either directly or as part of your project directory, try stripping them out and running `npm i` (or `yarn` or whatever you're using) in the container instead.

Comment: @JaredSmith That's it! I was using the `node_module` from the host system.